# Should the .tool-versions file of asdf go into .gitignore?

Tags: elixir, asdf-vm

I was wondering what best practice is here? The Elixir version is defined in the `mix.exs` anyways and different developers might want to use different OTP versions (compatible with the Elixir version) or different minor Elixir versions.

On the other hand it simplifies things and might make bug tracking easier if everyone uses exactly the same version.

Comment: In the projects I work on it's usually checked into git and sometimes even used to determine the versions used to build a release.

Comment: If checked into a project I'd recommend having some kind of standard or process for what versions to use. If every project has its own pinned versions you can end up with a lot of installs on your machine. I've got probably a dozen versions of erlang installed from touching various projects.

Comment: @BrettBeatty that's literally the point of asdf. you either mandate that only X version of tools is used and always make sure you spend time every 3 month updating every single one of your projects when you change that mandate, or you don't mandate and just use asdf.